# Download chunks a large files with StreamSaver Network Error

Tags: javascript, download, service-worker

I need to download a large file from the server (around >1GB) and I'm use the **StreamSaver**, but after 5 minutes the **service worker** is killed by chrome, and my download is canceled with Network Error.

I request chunks from server, because I'm get the file from azure api and if I  download from azure first and after send to browser i will get OutOfMemory exception.

I looked for everywhere and i didn't find, please i need help or to keep service work alive or another way do this.

obs: I looked at [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) repository issues, but i doesn't understand this [solution](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/issues/39).

obs 2: Sorry for my google translate english.